# In Vim, why can't I remap keys to `w`?

Tags: vim

In my `.vimrc`:

```
noremap z w
```

When I examine the mappings, `:map z` shows only:

```
z         * w
```

When I press `z`, my cursor moves as expected (to the next word). However, when I try to use something like `diz` or `ciz`, nothing happens. At the bottom of my screen, `di` and`ci` appear as I'm typing them, but once I type `z`, Vim gleefully sits idle. `diw` and `ciw` still work as expected.

What else do I need to do? Is there a mapping mode I don't know about?

Comment: I am also wondering, what's the difference between dw & diw ?

Comment: @dhruva, `dw` deletes text from the current cursor position to the wherever the cursor lands after you press `w`. :)

Comment: @ClosureCowboy I know that, but my question was different...

Comment: @dhruva, `diw` deletes the word under the cursor. I should have mentioned that in my previous comment!

Comment: Remap **z**? And what happens with **z<cr> zo z+ z- zl zh zt zz z. zM zR z^ zs zb z<left> z<right> zc** and **ze**? :-P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `iw` is a single text object, it is not modifier `i` + motion `w`. You need to map `iz` and `az` in this case:

```
onoremap iz iw
onoremap az aw
```

. Note that this will wait for you to press `z` only for some amount of time (see `:h 'timeoutlen'`). To make it work like `iw` (e.g., wait for `z` forever), you should try the following:

```
function s:MapTOPart(tostart)
    let char=getchar()
    if type(char)==type(0)
        let char=nr2char(char)
    endif
    return a:tostart.((char is# 'z')?('w'):(char))
endfunction

onoremap iz iw
onoremap az aw
onoremap <expr> i <SID>MapTOPart('i')
onoremap <expr> a <SID>MapTOPart('a')
```

You will have to do the same for all `i*` and `a*` text objects you use because with the above code only `iz` and `az` works fine; for some reason `iw` must be either typed too slow or typed as `iww`.

Comment: You've shattered my dreams. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is not with trying to bind to 'w', but instead, you're using the 'wrong' mapping. Granted, `:noremap z w` is what you want when you're in normal mode, but after `d` or `c`, Vim isn't in normal mode anymore!

Commands such as `d` and `c` enter a new mode, called "Operator Pending Mode". Google for more information, or see `:help Operator-pending` within vim. Therefore, what you want is the following *additional* line in your **~/.vimrc**:

```
onoremap z w
```

Afterwards, `diz` and `ciz` should work fine.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, `noremap` covers `operator-pending` mode. Just in case, I tried it, and it didn't work. Does this work for you?

Comment: Ah, you are right. I misread `noremap` as a normal mode map, rather than a generic mapping. (The normal mode only version is `nnoremap`.) Regardless, I just checked, but `diw` or `ciw` does not work either, at least in plain Vim. With `noremap z w`, `dz` works just like `dw`, but `diz` does nothing. Are you using any plugins? What is the result of `:omap w`?

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is simple:

> iw            "inner word", select [count]
>   words (see |word|).           White space
>   between words is counted too.             When
>   used in Visual linewise mode "iw"
>   switches to           Visual characterwise
>   mode.

You can remap w to z, but the iw is one command, not i+w.
Ex: dz works after:

> :omap z iw

Answer (score 1):

I don't think vim allows you to remap motions - and in your example, 'w' is a part of a motion ('iw'), not a command.

Remaping the 'z' key to the 'w' command worked because vim does allow you to remap commands.

Comment: @svec, this'll be soul-crushing if true. If I remap `w` to something else, I can't use the word motion at all. That doesn't sound right... or at least I hope it isn't!

Comment: @ClosureCowboy interesting but I tried the same scenario, I did `noremap w d` and then after that I did `ww`. It actually worked just like `dw`. What I gather from this is that commands & motions are treated differently, which makes sense as well, when we map keys, we map them to commands only, the motions however cannot be overridden (from what I see)

Comment: @svec Rats. You're right about that. I must've messed up my test. I'll prowl the internets in search of a way to do this.

Comment: You're right, but **w** is not exactly part of a motion, it's a text object.

Comment: -1: Vim does allow to remap text objects, but text object is `iw`, not `i`+`w`.

Comment: @Dhruva Sagar. If you can reproduce «I did `noremap w d` and then after that I did `ww`. It actually worked just like `dw`.» in a shell script with `vim -u NONE` it is a bug (perhaps of an earlier vim). When I tested this mapping, I got exactly the same result both for `ww` and for `dd`.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because of the fact that 'z' is used for a series of commands itself. Check out :h z

Comment: It doesn't work if you map it to something else either. For e.g. `noremap ; w` doesn't work.

Comment: @yoda is right. I've tried many keys, and none of them "completely" map to `w`.